# meaning of "Tab" in context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "Tab" here?

```
Usage:  I seem to have mislaid my wallet; can you put this on my tab?
```

I researched on the word "[tab](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=B-OQW-eZEof7vASv_aHIAw&q=tab%20meaning&oq=tab%20meaning&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i131k1j0l9.301.1940.0.2003.11.9.0.0.0.0.309.1021.0j4j0j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..6.5.1014....0.Af_D_LKVw00)" but none of them fits here.

Comment: my confusion was.. the tab ( bill ) is always there for you to make payment. so how does it matter whether wallet is lost or not. what matters is how are you going to pay now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definition 2b [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tab).  It refers to a running list of debts to pay.  To "put it on your tab", you're asking the clerk (usually bartender) to simply postpone payment for another day.

Comment: To ask for something to be put on your tab assumes that you have a credit agreement or, at least, an understanding with the person or outfit concerned. This generally allows someone to run up a number of debts while he/she awaits the money necessary to settle them - generally on *pay day*,.